# Computer building issues

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply

I currently have a Lenovo computer with a decent processor ( [Intel i5-3550 @3.30GHz](http://ark.intel.com/products/65516/Intel-Core-i5-3550-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_70-GHz)) and a Lenovo MAHOBAY motherboard.

I want to to buy a GTX 1060 and put it in this computer. There is some things I know you should have in mind before buying a graphics card:

- Checking if the power supply has enough wattage for it.
- Checking if it physically fits.

However I do not know how to check these 2 parameters. [This is the computer model's website](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/desktops/thinkcentre/m-series-towers/m92p-sff/#tab-tech_specs)

What I want to know is if the PSU is good enough and if it will fit or not in the computer.

Chassis Dimensions:  3.9" x 15.2" x 13.3"

Power Supply: 
SFF: 92% 240W Single Output PSU
SFF: 85% 240W Single Output PSU

Comment: The specific dimensions of the board are on the products specification website.  Determine, by using a ruler, if the card will fit into the case.  After you confirm that's the case, determine what PSU and much watts it supports, and verify the most wattage the card requires is below the wattage the PSU outputs.

Answer (score 0):

In most OEM system builds (Dell/HP/IBM/Lenovo), you will have to inspect the power supply by hand.

Most, if not all power supplies, will spell out the wattage with a sticker placed on themselves.

As for the physical dimensions, you will have to measure it yourself. "Extended length" graphics cards are known to have issues in cases where they could potentially extend past the motherboard. This is common with mini-ITX and micro-ATX boards. Again, the OEM could have used a custom board dimension, and leaves you no where but guessing or searching online.

Comment: In the provided link, it does specify the Power Supply wattage and the case's dimensions. I will post them here for easier access  Power Supply:  SFF: 92% 240W Single Output PSU
SFF: 85% 240W Single Output PSU Chassis Dimensions:  3.9" x 15.2" x 13.3" I just dont know how to interpret this data